# How to to create licensing library to handle enable/disable the features

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

We have been asked to build a web application with some pages (consider one page is one feature), and the requirement is to create licensing library to handle enable/disable the features.

1. The license meta-data should be available in XML file and the license class should be created in a dynamic way.
2. The license meta-data XML file could contain a flag to enable/disable the available features.
3. The license meta-data XML file could contain number limitations for example: maximum number of users, maximum number of customers etc.
4. License code should be created and encrypted and stored in a license file.
5. On starting the application it will decrypt the license code as per the license meta-data XML at run-time then apply the parameters on its features.
   Example on the license meta-data

   Notification
       Dispatcher
       Authentication
       Printing
       Max Users
       Max clients

Example on the license code before encryption
Example on the license code before encryption
[image]

Note: the XML above is only example, and it can be changed depends on the product and the client. So the licensing should be done dynamically at run-time.

Can you please give some idea or any example to do this.. thanks

Comment: You can pass the licensing information, including enabling and disabling of feature information inside of a license key.  You would have to come up with a method of generating a license key, but it should be opaque, self-validating, and leave room for information storage.

Comment: Can you please suggest any examples links.. because i don't have any idea

Comment: Just posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to reference various parts of System.Security, specifically **System.Security**, and **System.Security.Cryptography**.

Using symmetric cryptography methods you would generate a hash from a string variable that contains some pre-decided information.

Then you would probably use a cryptographically strong random number generator to some how seed your license key.  Part of your key would contain random bits of information, including the data you need to retrieve or validate, while some part of your key would contain instructions for decoding and reassembling the key into something readable.  This is called self-validation.  The idea of spreading the required data randomly across your license key is called opacity.  You can use nonces and proof-of-work algorithms that force whoever is decoding your key to take certain steps in a certain order for self-validation and data recovery to occur.

After you get your generated license key, you need to validate it. This is achieved by adding a LicenseProvider attribute to the class or component that you want to license.  You would implement your own LicenseProvider that would deal with the key that you just created.

[This Microsoft Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/fe8b1eh9%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) deeply covers licensing controls and components for runtime use.

Comment: If this answers your question will you mark it as correct, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use the excellent [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm) which allows us to embed metadata as part of the license that we check at runtime to enable various features. It's a very good product and while it costs a a few hundred bucks, it's more than worth it in my opinion. You not only get licensing, there are a whole other bunch of features to this product also for protecting your IP.